# Good place to publish funded grant proposals

Tags: publications, journals, ethics, funding, research-proposal

I have two grants and I would like to publish their proposals for which I received funding.

- Should I publish them in the first place? I think it would look good being transparent, and it would certainly be informative about what I'm currently working on (I am at least 6-8 months away from publishing my first results from these research). But I also think that it can have drawbacks like others thinking I'm just trying to pad my CV, or giving space to any and all kind of accusations about my research topic or about the quality of my proposal (I'm in the Social Sciences from a CEE country where social research is becoming more and more ideology-driven. I already have bad experiences about ideologically biased attacks and accusations against my academical activities)
- Where and in what form should I publish it? Should it be a self-publication on my institutional or personal website, academic social media account, in a repository etc.? Or should I find specific journals that publish grant proposals? (Do such journals exists? I found one https://riojournal.com but it looks like I have to pay them a fee for this).
- In my CV there is a section for funding. If I publish my funded grant proposals, should these items go to "Publications" or should I add them to "Awarded Funding"?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: About your first question: _Should I publish them in the first place?_ Did you ask your funding agency?

Comment: No. I'm not obliged to make it public (there is nothing about this in the funding contract). I can ask them about it, sure.

Comment: I can think of a few reasons *not* to make them public, from my experience (your case may differ). I have used preliminary (unpublished) results, half-baked ideas, copyrighted figures (owned by others) and things like that in my proposals. Making them public would incur in (possible) copyright violation and the risk of being scooped. You can of course get permission for copyrighted material before publication, but the risk of getting scooped is always there.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, publishing grant proposals (successful or not) is highly uncommon in the sciences (I've not come across that and don't know of a suitable platform). There is an obvious reason for that: proposals contain new ideas which the applicants plan to pursue in the future, so publishing them invites others to do the same and potentially scoop them.

Ideas are the scientist's capital (in particular for theoretical research) and unless they have a substantial overabundance of *good* ideas, they must be careful to not give them away too cheaply. Of course, in experimental/applied research an idea must be accompanied by the necessary resources and equipment (i.e. an advantage over any competitor) before it can be successfully pursued.

In your CV, you should list the grants with title, period, and value. However, the proposals themselves are not listed in a CV, they are definitely not publications.